# ASP.NET Core 6 Web Service: using compression

Tags: asp.net-core, compression

ASP.NET Core 6 web service: I deploy it as AWS Lambda function. I'd like to minimize traffic for some `GET` methods.

The question is: I'll add `app.UseResponseCompression()`, so should client applications add some special actions for handling the compressed responses, or will they work the same way as for non-compressed responses?
I'd like to compress/minimize data returned by GET methods from a database ( AWS NET 6 Lambda<->RDS PostgreSQL)

Comment: Depends on the client... For .NET's HttpClient for example, you need to specify which compression algorithms it should automatically decompress.

Comment: What about Swagger? Can it decompress if needed?

Comment: Swagger lets your browser do the decompression.

Comment: Add your answer and I'll mark it.